# Display drop down while typing character match - Angular 1 | ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I wanna make the text field as like search box and if the characters match I wanna showcase the list in the drop down that user to select the matched options.

The response is like below:

```
[
{
UserId:"12345",
Username:"Suthan M"
},
{
UserId:"12346",
Username:"Suksha"
}
]
```

I tried some blogs and Github lib they mentioned AutoComplete but it's not fair. I wanna make it short and sweet. If you having any options or suggestions please make a brief. It would be useful for me to capture the activity.

Example snap:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/tnr2394/autoCompleteTextbox

You see example and if satisfied to your then use this.

Comment: Hi Yash - Thanks for your answer but as of now I'm using the below one. https://github.com/umar-siddiqui/ion-select-autocomplete

Comment: Thank you ... that select auto complete is perfect solution for you